# How to use a variable from another file in the same package

Tags: go

I am pretty used to import a different package and use global variable of function from it. But all my search on the internet pointed me to the fact that I can't import a file. Just packages. But my IDEs (tried this in both IntelliJ and VS Code) are not able to refer to the variable. The code is as follows:

Here is my folder structure

```
.
├── QuickPOCinGo.iml
├── cmd
│   └── data
│       └── assets.go
├── go.mod
└── main.go
```

this is the `go.mod` file

```
// go.mod
module QuickPOCinGo

go 1.21
```

Here is the `assets.go` file

```
package main

var Assets = []string{"guitar", "laptop", "phone"}
```

Here is the `main.go`

```
package main

import "log"

func main() {
    log.Println("This is a simple project")

    for i, a := range Assets { # Assets variable is not getting resolved
        log.Printf("Index is %d and name is %s", i, a)
    }
}
```

`assets.go` and `main.go` are both in the main package. Not sure how to go around it all the resources found online aren't dealing with same package references.

Comment: you cannot directly import a file, only packages,but, you can create a separate package within your project to encapsulate the variables or functions you want to access from multiple files! if you want I can fix it for you!

Comment: You cannot import a main package. One folder == one package. Please take the Tour of Go and read go.dev/doc.

Comment: Please I recommend you reading the [Tour of Go (Official Go Website)](https://go.dev/tour), since I see that you are learning blindly. The problem you are having is a module problem, a module main (also called package) cannot import another module main

Comment: Thanks @Freeman can you share your thoughts on the solution proposed by soheil-khaledabadi  below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I told,you can not directly import a file, only packages,but, you can create a separate package within your project to encapsulate the variables or functions you want to access from multiple files, so in your example, you can create a package called `data` and move the `assets.go` file into that package, after that, in your `main.go` file, you can import the `data` package and access the `Assets` variable as `data.Assets`.

let me show you how, for example this is your structure :

```
├── QuickPOCinGo.iml
   ├── cmd
   │   └── main.go
   ├── go.mod
   └── data
       └── assets.go
```

so first of all edit and declare package into your `assets.go` file like below :

```
package data
var Assets = []string{"guitar", "laptop", "phone"}
```

and then update your `main.go` to import the `data` package and access the `Assets` like below :

```
package main

   import (
       "log"
       "your_module_path/data"
   )

   func main() {
       log.Println("This is a simple project")
       for i, a := range data.Assets {
           log.Printf("Index is %d and name is %s", i, a)
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you must import package data and get package `data.Assets` like this

I,edit your code im hope fix your bug

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "QuickPOCinGo/cmd/data"
)

func main() {
    log.Println("This is a simple project")

    for i, a := range data.Assets {
        log.Printf("Index is %d and name is %s", i, a)
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works if I change the package from the assets.go from man to data. While it doesn't hurt to refactor the code to use the data package. The main question remained unanswered . it seems not straight forward when both files are in the same package